# Defining a default argument as a global variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, default-value

Suppose I have a Python function `foo` which takes a default argument, where that default is set to some global variable. If I now change that global variable before calling the function, the default argument is still set to the original value of that global variable.

For example:

```
x = 1

def foo(a=x):
    print a

x = 2
foo()
```

This prints `1`, instead of `2`.

How should I be writing my code, so that I can change this global variable, and have it update this default argument?

Comment: Default arguments are evaluated only once...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A default variable **is only evaluated and set once**. So Python makes a copy **of the reference** and from then on, it always passes that reference as default value. No re-evaluation is done.

You can however solve this by using **another object** as default object, and then use an `if` statement to substitute it accordingly. Something like:

```
the_default = object()
x = 1

def foo(a = the_default):
    if a is the_default:
        a = x
    print a

x = 2
foo()
```

Note that we use `is` to perform *reference equality*. So we check if it is  indeed the `default_object`. You should not use the `the_default` object somewhere else in your code.

In many Python code, they use `None` as a default (and thus reduce the number of objects the construct). For instance:

```
def foo(a = None):
    if a is None:
        a = x
    print a
```

Note however that if you do that, your program cannot make a distinction between a user calling `foo()` and `foo(None)` whereas using something as `the_object` makes it harder for a user to obtain a reference to that object. This can be useful if `None` would be a valid candidate as well: if you want `foo(None)` to print `'None'` and not `x`.

Comment: as the_deault you can just use 'None', unless None is a valid value for the argument

Comment: @CarloLobrano: yes. I updated the answer at the same moment you wrote that comment. The only problem can be that you want to *exclude* the fact that users themselves can feed that object. By using something as `the_object`, you are more protected against that behavior.

Comment: that's correct. It's wiser to use "default objects" than None sometimes