# Change a global variable that is used as default argument in a decorator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, global

I have a function that uses a global `x` variable as default value for its argument. However, in the `main()` function called in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block I would like to allow the user to change this variable in order to modify the behavior of the function. This does not seem to work because when I run the script `x` in the function is already occupied with 9 in this case and not changed to 10, as I would like to have it.

```
x = 9

def function(var=x):
    print(var)

def main():
    global x
    x = 10
    function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Simply calling `function(var=x)` in `main()` would not work in my case because `function()` is actually a decorator and it is rather:

```
from module import decorator

x = 9

@decorator(var1=x, var2=15)
def function():
    pass

def main():
    global x
    x = 10
    function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, the decorator is imported from another module so I think the answer posted in [Defining a default argument as a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718870/defining-a-default-argument-as-a-global-variable) might not work either. Even more complicated, the decorator is supposed to take other arguments as well, so using a class as suggested by **kederrac** below does not work either.  However, since this module is made by myself I could copy the necessary code into my new script but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `class` as a decorator

```
class my_decorator:
    x = 9

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(my_decorator.x)
            return self.f(*args, **kwargs)



@my_decorator
def function():
    pass

def main():
    my_decorator.x = 4
    function()

main()

# 4
```

---

if you want to pass a param to your decorator you may use:

```
from functools import partial

class my_decorator:
    x = 9

    def __init__(self, f, param1):
        self.f = f
        self.param1 = param1

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(my_decorator.x)
            print(self.param1)
            return self.f(*args, **kwargs)



@partial(my_decorator, param1='test_param')
def function():
    pass

def main():
    my_decorator.x = 4
    function()

main()

# 4
# test_param
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in the *Python Cookbook* by *Beazley and Jones*, chapter 9.5. They introduce accessor functions which are able to change variables by the use of `nonlocal`. I have attached an example solution.

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def attach_wrapper(obj, func=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(attach_wrapper, obj)
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)
    return func

def decorator(arg1, arg2):
    def decorate(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwarg):
            ...
            do_something_with_arg1_and_arg2
            ...
            return func(*args, **kwargs)            

        @attach_wrapper(wrapper)
        def set_arg1(new_arg1):
            nonlocal arg1
            arg1 = new_arg1
        return wrapper
    return decorate
```

So now you can decorate your `function()` with the `decorator`and subsequently change arg1 using `set_arg1()` as a method of `function()` like so:

```
@decorator(arg1=9, arg2=15)
def function():
    pass

function.set_arg1(10)
```

The only thing is, that in this case I need to call this method for all the functions I am applying the decorator on, so also not ideal.