# global variable as default argument in python function

Tags: python, global-variables, default-arguments

I am trying to write a python function with an optional argument *tr*, if this argument was not specified, then I want to take a global variable instead.

```
DEF_tARGET = "UserA"
def display_target(tr=DEF_TARGET):
    print(tr)
```

The problem is that when I change the global variable somewhere in my program, then call the function with no *tr* argument, the function is still taking the initial value (when the function was declared) of the global variable. See the example below:

```
DEF_TARGET = "UserA"
def display_target(tr=DEF_TARGET):
    print(f"target is {tr}")

display_target("UserB")     # prints UserB

DEF_TARGET = "UserB"
display_target()
```

**Output**

```
target is UserA
```

**Expected**

```
target is UserB
```

I could declare the function as below, but I was looking for a better approach

```
def display_target(tr=None):
    if not tr:
        tr = DEF_TARGET
    print(f"target is {tr}")
```

Comment: Don't use `if not tr`.  Use `if tr is None`.  Lots of things other than `None` evaluate to false (`False`, `0`, `""`, etc.)

Comment: Using solution based upon `if tr is None` is the [standard answer for global as default parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718870/defining-a-default-argument-as-a-global-variable)

Comment: Thank you, so the default variable is only evaluated and set once at the declaration of the function.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you for this note. I actually uses `tr = tr or DEF_TARGET`, which does the same.

Comment: @Shadowfax Yes, that has the exact same problem:  If `tr` is `False` or `0` or `""` or anything else that evaluates to `False`, you'll ignore it and use `DEF_TARGET` instead.  Change it to `tr = DEF_TARGET if tr is None else tr` if you want a one-line assignment.

Comment: @TomKarzes yeah sure, you're right. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour in python when defining your function is the following:

- Create a function object
- Compile your code and store it in the object
- Make sure everything (e.g. variables) needed to run the code will by available when you want to launch the function

In the case of the defaults arguments they are stored either in the attribute `__defaults__` or in `__kwdefaults__`. And in the case of the basic types like strings, char, int or float they are copied to this location.

So the definitive response is no. You cannot force python to create a reference for you here. But if you just want to make you code prettier, that is possible:

```
def display_target(tr=None):
    tr = tr or DEF_TARGET
    print(f"target is {tr}")
```